# The topology inherited by $\Bbb{R}$ from $\Bbb{R_\ell}\times \Bbb{R}$.

Tags: general-topology

What kind of topology does $\Bbb{R}$ inherit from $\Bbb{R_\ell}\times \Bbb{R}$? For instance, take the open set $[1,2)\times (3,4)\in \Bbb{R_\ell}\times \Bbb{R}$. What is $[1,2)\times (3,4)\cap\Bbb{R}$?

Is it $[1,2)$? Or should it be $\emptyset$ (diagramatically speaking)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Depends what you mean by $\mathbb R$, at least the set of points that would characterise the real line as a subspace of $\mathbb R_\ell\times\mathbb R$.

Comment: Kind of depends on how you're thinking of $\mathbb{R}$ inside of $\mathbb{R}_\ell\times\mathbb{R}$, but I assume you equate $\mathbb{R}$ with $\mathbb{R}\times\{0\}$ in which case it gets the $\mathbb{R}_\ell$ topology.

Comment: @Bryan- In what other ways could $\Bbb{R}$ be thought of? And if it gets the $\Bbb{R_\ell}$ topology, does that mean what the intersection of open sets in $\Bbb{R_\ell}\times \Bbb{R}$ with $\Bbb{R}$ essentially does is find the projection map onto $\Bbb{R}$?

Comment: That is not visually intuitive. If I were to draw $[1,2)\times(3,4)$ on the $\Bbb{R^2}$ plane, I would get a rectangle above the $\Bbb{R}$ line. So shouldn't the intersection of the open set with the $\Bbb{R}$ line be the empty set?

Answer (score 1):

Two extreme cases: if by $\mathbb{R}$ you mean $\mathbb{R}\times \left\{ 0 \right\} \subset \mathbb{R}_l \times \mathbb{R} $, then the answer is $\mathbb{R}_l$, as Bryan pointed you out.

On the other hand, if you mean $\left\{ 0 \right\}\times \mathbb{R}  \subset \mathbb{R}_l \times \mathbb{R} $, then the answer would be $\mathbb{R}$, by which I mean with the usual, Euclidian topology.

If you included $\mathbb{R} \subset \mathbb{R}_l \times \mathbb{R} $ as other kind of straigh lines...?